# How to debug using Docker on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have kafka running in a docker container on my Maac. Here is how i start it

```
#Start Zookeeper 
docker run -d -p 2181:2181 --net myNet --name myZookeeper myRegistry/kafka:0.10.1.0 zookeeper-server-start

#Start Kafka 
export KAFKA_ADVERTISE_HOSTNAME="my.ip.add"

docker run -d --net br-advisor-nw  --name whi-kafka -p 9092:9092 --link myZookeeper:myZookeeper myRegistry/kafka:0.10.1.0 kafka-server-start --override zookeeper.connect=${KAFKA_ADVERTISE_HOSTNAME}:2181  --override broker.id=0 --override advertised.host.name=${KAFKA_ADVERTISE_HOSTNAME} --override group.max.session.timeout.ms=3600000 --override auto.create.topics.enable=false --override replica.fetch.max.bytes=10485760 --override message.max.bytes=10485760 --override port=9092 --override  listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

I can see the containers running in Docker, and i can ssh into the containers just fine.

Now, I am trying to connect to the container from my host machine as

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper my.ip.add:2181
```

but this fails to connect. I have also tried

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 0.0.0.0:2181

kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 127.0.0.0:2181

kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

but they all fail. I also tried to get the IP of the container from

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' myZookeeper
```

gives

```
ip.of.container
```

but

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper ip.of.container:2181
```

fails as well.

**Is there any way for me to connect to kafka/zookeeper running inside the docker container?**

Also, it appears that although i am using the `-p` flag, neither of the ports are exposed. Why is that?

Comment: Is the container running and listening (`docker ps` and `docker logs`)? Configured to listen on 0.0.0.0 (not 127.0.0.1)? What does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` show?

Comment: that shows

`tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using docker-toolbox/docker-machine on your Mac to run docker. This creates a Linux VM under the covers but doesn't have some of the features of the xhyve release that hides the VM. You'll see it running in virutalbox, and you'll see it in the IP address you need to use to connect to your containers.

You should be able to run:

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 192.168.99.100:2181
```

To lookup your IP in the future, you can use `docker-machine ip`. If your install of Mac is new enough, you may want to upgrade to a newer version that uses xhyve.